# The first and second variation of a given functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

**My Question:** Find first and second variation of following functional $$J(u)=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}(1+u'^2)\sqrt{u}dt$$

**My Answer:** I found first variation of the functional as
$$\delta J=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\big[\frac{(1-u'^2)}{2\sqrt{u}}- 2u''\sqrt{u} \big]\delta u dt$$
Is it right?

But I can' t find second variation of the functional.
Could you help me?

Comment: It seems you are after something similar to $$\delta J(u)=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\left((1+u'(t)^2)\frac{\delta u(t)}{2\sqrt{u(t)}}+2u'(t)\sqrt{u(t)}\delta u'(t)\right)dt$$ but your post is missing so much context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the first variation is right.  The integrand for the  second variation is given by

$$
\frac14\frac{(\frac{d}{dt}u(t))^2-4(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}u(t))u(t)-1}{u(t)^{3/2}}
$$

This result is obtained using the Euler-Lagrange equation with the form

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial u}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}\right)+\frac{d^2}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial u''}\right)=0$$

where $L$ is given by the integrand in the first variation

$${\color{blue}L}=\frac{(1-u'^2)}{2\sqrt u}-2u''\sqrt{u}$$

More formally we write

$$\delta^2 J=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\big[\frac14\frac{(\frac{d}{dt}u(t))^2-4(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}u(t))u(t)-1}{u(t)^{3/2}}]\delta^2 u dt$$

Comment: I do not  know why my answer was deleted but it is the correct answer. Please verify it.

Comment: I do not know why your answer was deleted. Which formula of second variation did you use? Could you explain in more detail? Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. Lastly, How can we test whether it is right or not?

Comment: @1_student,  I am checking the result with Maple and I am obtaining the same result. I am completely sure that the result is right.  All the best.

Comment: Thanks. Best regards